# Magento Enterprise (1.14) modify admin password via database

Tags: magento-enterprise, database

How do I go about changing an admin account password in the database in Magento 1.14 (enterprise)

Is it sha(256) with a 32 character salt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find that you actually don't need to add the salt to reset the Magento EE passwords. A simple MD5 reset will work from my experience:

```
UPDATE `admin_user` SET `password` = MD5('NEWPASSWORD') WHERE `username` = 'ADMINUSERNAME';
```